# Android strange IndexOutOfBounds exception

Tags: android, arrays, exception

I am looping through an Arraylist.
`fotoPath` is an arraylist, containing the paths of all picture's thumbnails of the phone (via Images.Thumbnails.DATA).
`fotoWhatsApp` is an arraylist with the `BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME` of each pic.

```
for (int i = 0; i < fotoPath.size(); i++) {
    if (fotoWhatsApp.get(i).equals("WhatsApp Images")) {
        whatsApp.add(fotoPath.get(i));
    }
}
```

I used this code on phones with only a few taken pictures on them, where it worked perfectly.

Then I used it on two devices, containing a large number (>1100) pictures on it.

Then logcat showed me an IndexOutOfBound Exception for the second line in the code above.

> "IndexOutOfBound Exception. Index is 1354, size is 1354."

What do I miss here?

Comment: It looks like fotoPath.size() is greater than the size of fotoWhatsApp.size()

Comment: but Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME and Images.Thumbnails.DATA should both deliver the same amount of images, shouldn't they? and why did it work on 4 devices, and it didn't on 2 others... hmm

Comment: I'm not sure how the API works, but you can run the app in a debugger and see if you can track down where the inconsistent sizes are coming from.